# Temporary Lucene exception "there are more terms than documents in field "xyz", but it's impossible to sort on tokenized fields"

Tags: caching, lucene

In a client's software component Lucene 2.9 is used and they use a lot of index properties, some are tokendized, some are not. We assume property `xyz` is added to the index like this:

index.add(new Field("xyz", value, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.UN_TOKENIZED));

When we create new objects in the index (let's say 150 new objects in 3 seconds), I saw a temporary exception where the software tried to perform a sorted search on one of the `UNTOKENIZED` properties:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: there are more terms than documents in field "xyz", but it's impossible to sort on tokenized fields
        at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldCacheImpl$StringIndexCache.createValue(FieldCacheImpl.java:706) ~[lucene-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2 912433 - 2010-02-21 23:51:08]
        at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldCacheImpl$Cache.get(FieldCacheImpl.java:208) ~[lucene-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2 912433 - 2010-02-21 23:51:08]
        at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldCacheImpl.getStringIndex(FieldCacheImpl.java:676) ~[lucene-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2 912433 - 2010-02-21 23:51:08]
        at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldComparator$StringOrdValComparator.setNextReader(FieldComparator.java:667) ~[lucene-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2 912433 - 2010-02-21 23:51:08]
        at org.apache.lucene.search.TopFieldCollector$OneComparatorNonScoringCollector.setNextReader(TopFieldCollector.java:94) ~[lucene-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2 912433 - 2010-02-21 23:51:08]
        at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:245) ~[lucene-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2 912433 - 2010-02-21 23:51:08]
        at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:236) ~[lucene-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2 912433 - 2010-02-21 23:51:08]
        at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:179) ~[lucene-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2 912433 - 2010-02-21 23:51:08]
        at org.apache.lucene.search.Hits.getMoreDocs(Hits.java:113) ~[lucene-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2 912433 - 2010-02-21 23:51:08]
        at org.apache.lucene.search.Hits.<init>(Hits.java:90) ~[lucene-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2 912433 - 2010-02-21 23:51:08]
        at org.apache.lucene.search.Searcher.search(Searcher.java:63) ~[lucene-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2 912433 - 2010-02-21 23:51:08]
```

The exception could be observed for some seconds / minutes, and then it disappeared.

The index holds about 1 million indexed objects.

I know ask the following:
is there any known issue related to untokenized properties, like any asynchronous internal Lucene logic that runs after adding a new object to the index? At least when looking at the stacktrace above, there seems to be a fieldcache that might get corrupt temporarily under some circumstances? I thought that Lucene does not do anything after I added an object to the index.

Thanks for any advice (and please don't tell me to upgrade Lucene, I told it about 100 times to my client.)

Comment: Been a considerable while since I worked with 2.9. Might try: after writing the new records, call `IndexWriter.optimize`, and wait for it to complete before opening a new `IndexReader`.

Comment: Thanks, we tried to use `IndexWriter.optimize` due to other needs, but as it is a synchronous call and takes many seconds to complete (the index is quite large), we can not use this. But your recommendation gives me the impression that my assumption of internal caching mechanisms is probably not that wrong.

Comment: Definitely a guess, but I'd suspect it having something to do with updates/deletions needing to be merged in. Basically, the term count being out of sync with the doc count. Maybe it's getting a correct doc count, but is counting terms from docs flagged for deletion in its terms count, or the opposite, it's seeing the new terms in the term count, but not getting an accurate doc count until the new ones get merged in. Are you calling commit() after adding the docs? And if optimize solves it, would it be possible to run optimize in the background, and keep an IndexReader alive until it finishes?

Comment: @femtoRgon: as far as I know, version 2.9 is blocking anything if you call `commit()`, so this is not a real solution as I think this call will take some minutes to finish with the size of our index.